# awk to update file with sum of matching `another file

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to add a penalty to a score to each matching `$1` in `file2` based on the sum of `$3+$4` (variable TL) in `file1`. Then the `$4` value in `file1` is divided by `TL` and multiplied by 100 (this valvue is variable S). Finally, `$2` in `file2` -S gives the updated `$2` result in `file2`. Since math is not my strong suit there probaly is a better way of doing this, but this is what I could think off.  Thank you :).

**file1**  `space delimited`

```
ACP5 4 1058 0
ACTB5 10 1708 79
ORAI1 2 952 0
TBX1 9 1932 300
```

**file2**  `tab-delimited`

```
ACP5     100.00
ACTB     100.00
ORAI1    94.01
TBX1     77.23
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`  the `---` is an example calculation and not part of the output

```
 ACP5    100.00
 ACTB    89.59   ---- $3+$4=1787 this is TL (comes from file1), $4/TL*100 is 4.42, $2 in file2 is 100 - 4.42 = 95.58 ----
 ORAI1   94.01
 TBX1    63.79
```

**awk**

```
awk '
FNR==NR{  # process each line
  TL[$1]=($3+$4);next} ($1 in TL)  # from file1 store sum of $3 and $4 in TL
    {S=(P[$4]/TL)*100;printf("%s\t %.2f\n",$1,  $2-S)  # store $4/TL from file1 in S and subtract S from $2 in file2, output two decimal places
      }1' OFS="\t" file1 FS="\t" file2  # update and define input
```

**current output**

```
ACP5     100.00
ACTB     100.00
ORAI1    94.01
TBX1     77.23
```

Comment: I was adding the `awk`, as I forgot. It does execute but the output is unchanged. I apologize and thank you :).

Comment: No, it is a one-liner, I will clean it up in the post.  Thank you :).

Comment: The script you now posted would, if not for the syntax errors, print each line from file2 twice. Also you're accessing an array `P[]` but you never populate it and then populating an array `TL[]` at the start of the script and then using `TL` as a scalar later in the script - this script not only wont produce the output you say it does, it'll just fail with syntax errors. When asking for help with a script, it's important to show the actual script you want help with. What you have posted now is just gibberish that cannot possibly do what you say it does.

Comment: now I am getting syntax errors `(FILENAME=file2 FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `TL' in a scalar context` as you already knew, I just re-ran the `awk`. Thank you :).

Comment: Just like @EdMorton pointed out in the previous comment. You can't divide by `TL` because TL is an array. I'll refrain from restating the rest of his comment a second time, though the temptation is incredible.

Comment: Maybe another quick comment : file1 has "ACTB5" while file2 has "ACTB". you will not find a TL match for ACTB

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the question is not completely clear. Since I can't comment yet I will give a solution that calculates the values as requested.

```
awk '
NF==4 {  S[$1] = 100 * $4 / ($3 + $4) }
NF==2 {  printf("%s\t%.2f\n", $1, $2 - S[$1]) }
' file1 file2
```

**file1**

```
ACP5 4 1058 0
ACTB 10 1708 79
ORAI1 2 952 0
TBX1 9 1932 300
```

**file2**

```
ACP5    100.00
ACTB    100.00
ORAI1   94.01
TBX1    77.23
```

**output**

```
ACP5    100.00
ACTB    95.58
ORAI1   94.01
TBX1    63.79
```

Explanation:
The script works by calculating and storing the `S` value in a associative array using `$1` as the key. This is done in a block filtered by `NF==4`, so it will only runs for the first file (the only one with 4 fields). Finally, for `NF==2` representing the second file, the result is printed using a printf and by subtracting the corresponding `S` value from `$2`.

Observation: *Keep in mind that as @kvantour pointed out the example you provided does not follow the indications in the question. For example, where did the 89.59 value come from? The explanation ends up with 95.58 as the result just like the output of the script I provided*